# Setting img src doesn't generate GET request

Tags: javascript, html, http, python-3.x, httpserver

I currently have the following code (for personal use) for authorization with the Spotify Web API

```
import http.server
import urllib.parse
from subprocess import call

authQuery = {}
class queryStrHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print("received a get request")
        urlComponents = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path)
        if urlComponents[4] == "":
            print("sending payload")
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            html = """<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
            alert("payload has been activated");
            var tokenSupplier = document.createElement("img");
            if(window.location.hash){
                var fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1);
                alert(fragment);
                tokenSupplier.src = "http://localhost:8888/?" + fragment;
                alert(tokenSupplier.src);
            }
            else {
                var queryStr = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
                tokenSupplier.src = "http://localhost:8888/?" + queryStr;
            } 
            </script></head><body></body></html>"""
            self.wfile.write(bytes(html, "utf-8"))
        else:
            print("receiving token or error")
            global authQuery
            authQuery = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urlComponents[4])

tokenFetcher = http.server.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8888), queryStrHandler)
authUrl = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(
    {
        "client_id": "<ID here>",
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8888/",
        "scope": "playlist-read-private user-library-read",
        "response_type": "token"
    }
)
call(["open", authUrl])
tokenFetcher.handle_request()
print(authQuery)
```

Because the hash fragment in the url that the Spotify accounts service redirects the user to after the user has allowed access isn't sent to the server (this script), I am sending a HTML/JS payload when the Accounts service redirects the user to localhost:8888 that phones home the hash fragment containing the access token via the query string in the source url of a tracking pixel style image element. When this happens the else branch in the do_GET function should be executed. However setting the src of the image element never seems to generate a GET request as my script never reports a second GET request, as a result of this the authQuery dictionary that should contain the access token among other things remains empty. The strange thing is, when I hadn't added the code that opens the browser (the call line which utilizes OS X' open command that opens a URL or file in the default application) yet, but manually browsed to http://localhost:8888/?aParameter=someValueHere the 'tracking pixel' did work!

I have read that because of the caching behavior of browsers setting the src of an image might not generate a GET request, the suggested solution was adding a unique parameter to the src URL to avoid caching, however this shouldn't be necessary in my case, as the Spotify Web API access token in the src URL is already unique!

Comment: What they meant is to keep changing that unique id, in order to force GET reauest

Comment: I'm not sure how what you're saying is different from what I said :/ The access token is different every time the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting src="", then src="http://localhost:8888/?aParameter=someValueHere"

EDIT:

Try removing the IMG element from the DOM, then re-adding it with the new src
like so between each calls:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://localhost:8888/?aParameter=someValue_1";
ContainerElement.appendChild(img);

ContainerElement.removeChild(img);
img = null;
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://localhost:8888/?aParameter=someValue_2";
ContainerElement.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: @Superpelican I edited the answer to suggest removing the IMG element completely and re-adding it with the new src

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to improve your answer. I should note however that the img src is set only one time each time the script is run! So I believe your suggestion isn't necessary. Furthermore I have just replaced the tracking pixel technique with an XMLHttpRequest and even though the Network tab of the Firefox Debugging Console clearly shows the GET request with the access token in the URL is sent, my script still doesn't report a second GET request, this suggests that something is wrong with the server code and not the JS code!

Comment: Okay, I just solved the server side problem. The 'tracking pixel' code probably was fine, so this question can be closed IMHO. I'll just leave the XMLHttpRequest code in though, because it just is clearer and cleaner IMO.